# Tabulator Editor does not edit collapsed fields in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, tabulator

I am using Tabulator to display dynamic tables, I have successfully loaded the data into the table with Ajax. I can edit the rows in the table until I add the responsive layout property. After this has been applied only the top level rows can be edited and not the rows that have been collapsed down.

How to get this working?

```
    var table = new Tabulator("#Contacts", {

        layout: "fitDataFill",
        responsiveLayout: "collapse",
        pagination: "local",
        paginationSize: 15,
        columns: [
            { formatter: "responsiveCollapse", width: 30, minWidth: 30, align: "center", resizable: false, headerSort: false },
            { title: "ID"}, { title: "Company", headerFilter: true, editor: true }, { title: "Name", editor: true },
        { title: "Context Reference", editor: true }, { title: "Role", editor: true }, { title: "Department", editor: true },
        { title: "Lead Source1", editor: true }, { title: "Lead Source2", editor: true }, { title: "Account Rep", editor: true },
            { title: "Address 1",  editor: true }, { title: "Address 2", editor: true }, { title: "Address 3", editor: true },
            { title: "City", editor: true }, { title: "State", editor: true }, { title: "Post Code", editor: true },
        { title: "Country", editor: true }, { title: "Phone", editor: true }, { title: "Phone Extension", editor: true },
        { title: "Mobile", editor: true }, { title: "Fax", editor: true }, { title: "Fax Extension", editor: true },{ title: "Email Address", editor: true },
        { title: "Website", editor: true }, { title: "RecGUID", }, { title: "Terms", editor: true },
        { title: "Tax Rate", editor: true }, { title: "Tax Zone", editor: true }, { title: "Price Profile", editor: true },
        { title: "Accounting CustomerID", editor: true }, { title: "Account Number", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text01", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Text02", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text03", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text04", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Text05", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text06", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text07", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Text08", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text09", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text10", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Text11", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text12", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text13", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Text14", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Text15", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Number01", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Number02", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Number03", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Number04", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Number05", editor: true },{ title: "Custom Date01", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Date02", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Date03", editor: true },{ title: "Custom Date04", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Date05", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Memo01", editor: true },{ title: "Custom Memo02", editor: true }, { title: "Custom Memo03", editor: true },
        { title: "Custom Memo04", editor: true },{ title: "Custom Memo05", editor: true }, { title: "Notes", editor: true },
        ],
        cellEdited: EditRow,
    },);
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (version 4.1) collapsed columns are read only, editors are only applied fully visible columns.

This may be added onto the roadmap in the future, but wont be available for the next few releases at least

Comment: Thanks for getting back Oli,

Comment: no problemo, sorry it wasnt with a answer that could help you out more

Comment: @OliFolkerd any update on that feature? Do you have it on your roadmap?

Comment: Nope still not available I'm afraid

Comment: is this feature included in the latest release 5.5?